# ClarityNg: how to close sidenav on click button inside

Tags: angular, clarity, vmware-clarity

I have a basic clarity angular template with search in sidenav. When I click find button in sidenav on mobile device, sidenav does not disappear. How I can close sidenav using angular?

Comment: Can you share how you've created your template?

Comment: Yes, sure <clr-main-container>
  <clr-header>
        <div class="branding">
        </div>
        <div class="header-nav" [clr-nav-level]="1">
        </div>
    </clr-header>
    <div class="content-container">
        <main class="content-area">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </main>
        <nav class="sidenav" [clr-nav-level]="2">
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </nav>
    </div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be for you to get a reference to the `NavLevelDirective` instance for the sidenav with `@ViewChild`, and all its `close()` method.

For instance, add a reference variable in your template:

```
<nav #mySidenav class="sidenav" [clr-nav-level]="2">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</nav>
```

Then access it in your app's component by using:

```js
@ViewChild("mySidenav", {read: NavLevelDirective}) sidenav: NavLevelDirective;
```

and just call `sidenav.close()` when the user clicks the "find" button.